# Surface view: text draws on different layers

Tags: android, android-canvas, draw, surfaceview

Target: to draw text letter by letter

Result: text draws on different layers:
Text to draw : Hello World!!!

1. [image]
2. [image]

public class DrawThread extends Thread {
    public static final String TAG = DrawThread.class.getSimpleName();

```
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private String word;
private Paint paint;

public DrawThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, String word, Paint paint){
    this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    this.word = word;
    this.paint = paint;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    String letterToDraw;
    int wordLength = word.length();
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < wordLength){

        Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);

            letterToDraw = word.charAt(counter)+"";
            canvas.drawText(letterToDraw, 20 + counter*20, 40, paint);

        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        counter++;
        try {
            sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

}

public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView{
    private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

```
public MySurfaceView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    init();
}

public MySurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    init();
}

public MySurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    init();
}

private void init(){
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
    paint.setTextSize(45);
    paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
}

public void drawText(){
    DrawThread drawThread = new DrawThread(getHolder(), "Hello World!!!", paint);
    drawThread.run();
}
```

}

Comment: can You post a picture of the result for better understanding?

Comment: if You change the textSize, is it the same result?

Comment: Yes, the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that SurfaceView is double- or triple-buffered, and you're not redrawing the entire screen every time.  As a result, alternate letters are ending up in each buffer.

You should clear and redraw the entire screen every time you call `Canvas#lockCanvas()`.  Then just create an inner loop that draws the letters from 0 to `counter`, instead of only the one at `counter`.

(You will also need to take into account the width of each letter so they don't draw on top of each other, but that's a whole separate thing.)

Some background on Android graphics and SurfaceView behavior is available [here](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html).

Comment: "You should clear and redraw the entire screen" - you mean I must invalidate view?

Comment: No.  The SurfaceView has two parts, the "view" part, which is on a layer with all the other View elements, and the "surface" part, which is on its own hardware-composited layer.  Nothing you draw on the SurfaceView's surface will affect the View objects, and vice-versa.  What I'm saying is that, every time you draw on the surface, you need to start with `canvas.drawColor()` (or similar), and then issue draw commands for everything on screen.  You can do partial updates by specifying a dirty rect (but note the SurfaceView might expand the rect).